# Why `startActivityUpdates` update rate is low in background?

Tags: ios, core-motion

I am trying to detect when a user starts driving (or being driven) while the app is in the background.
The update rate of activity becomes very low while the app is background and this causes the app to miss the beginning of the drive. When the app is in the foreground, this problem does not exist.

Is there a way to remedy this?

Here is my code:

```
    func startMotionClassification() {
    guard CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() else {
        return
    }

    opQueue = {
        let o = OperationQueue()
        o.name = "core-motion-updates"
        return o
    }()
    
    self.motionActivityManager.startActivityUpdates(to: opQueue!) { activity in
        guard let activity = activity else {return}
        if (activity.automotive || Constants.IS_DEBUG) &&
            (activity.confidence == .medium || activity.confidence == .high) &&
            !self.isDriving {
            self.isDriving = true
            self.markStartOfTrip()
        }
        
        if !activity.automotive &&
                (activity.confidence == .high) &&
                self.isDriving {
            self.isDriving = false
            self.markEndOfTrip()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Core Motion updates are not delivered when your app is suspended.  Are you using some other background mode (such as Core Location updates) to get background execution?  As noted in the documentation "The handler block is executed on a best effort basis and updates are not delivered while your app is suspended. If updates arrived while your app was suspended, the last update is delivered to your app when it resumes execution. To get all of the updates that occurred while your app was suspended, use the queryActivityStarting(from:to:to:withHandler:) method"

Comment: So, you should save the date when your app `didEnterBackground` and then if you get an update later you can use the query function to fetch motion updates that occurred while your app was suspended

Comment: My app is using the “location update” background mode and it does receive some motion activity reports in the background; just not as frequent. Since I need the location when the “automotive” activity is detected, I can’t use the query after the fact (it doesn’t return the location associated with activity).

Comment: Unfortunately, motion updates are not an available background mode for ios. You are getting background updates opportunistically because of your background location updates. If you store the location updates then you should be able to query for the start of the motion change and correlate it with the location at that time.

Comment: Location updated are enable only after I detect a change in the motion activity. So it doesn’t seem that the location update is the trigger for activity (it’s the other way around)

Comment: Just curious if you ever worked around this?  I'm trying to solve a very similar problem in watchOS (I turn location updates off when the device has been stationary for several minutes in order to save battery life).  But I need some way to determine that the device has started moving again so I can turn them back on.  I thought Core Motion activity was exactly what I needed until I discovered this issue.

Comment: I ended up creating a geofence around where the user stops. When user crosses the geofence, I query core motion and determine if they are driving